# How do you set the width of an HTML Helper TextBox in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Some examples I found that apparently worked with older versions of mvc suggest that there was a length parameter of sorts:

```
<%=Html.TextBox("test", 50)%>
```

But that may have been mistakenly setting the value.

How do this work in the current release? Passing in the style doesn't appear to have any effect.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The original answer is no longer working as written:

```
<%=Html.TextBox("test", new { style="width:50px" })%>
```

will get you a text box with "{ style="width:50px" }" as its text content.

To adjust this for the current release of MVC 1.0, use the following script (note the addition of the second parameter - I have mine starting as blank, adjust accordingly based on your needs):

```
<%=Html.TextBox("test", "", new { style="width:50px" })%>
```

Answer (score 42):

For this you have to use **HtmlAttributes**, but there is a catch: [HtmlAttributes and css class](http://forums.asp.net/t/1304585.aspx) .

you can define it like this:

```
new { Attrubute="Value", AttributeTwo = IntegerValue, @class="className" };
```

and here is a more realistic example:

```
new { style="width:50px" };
new { style="width:50px", maxsize = 50 };
new {size=30, @class="required"}
```

and finally in:

MVC 1

```
<%= Html.TextBox("test", new { style="width:50px" }) %>
```

MVC 2

```
<%= Html.TextBox("test", null, new { style="width:50px" }) %>
```

MVC 3

```
@Html.TextBox("test", null, new { style="width:50px" })
```

Answer (score 6):

Something like this should work:

```
<%=Html.TextBox("test", new { style="width:50px" })%>
```

Or better:

```
<%=Html.TextBox("test")%>

<style type="text/css">
    input[type="text"] { width:50px; }     
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

I -strongly- recommend build your HtmlHelpers. I think that apsx code will be more readable, reliable and durable.

Follow the link;
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the length parameter as it will not work with all browsers. The best way is to set a style on the input tag.

```
<input style="width:100px" />
```

Answer (score 1):

My real sample for MVC 3 is here:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>

<p>

Start Date: <%: Html.TextBox("datepicker1", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), new { style = "width:80px;", maxlength = 10 })%> 

End Date: <%: Html.TextBox("datepicker2", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), new { style = "width:80px;", maxlength = 10 })%> 

<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Search" /> 

</p>

<% } %>
```

So, we have following

**"datepicker1"** - ID of the control

**DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"**) - value by default

**style = "width:80px;**" - width of the textbox

**maxlength = 10** - we can input 10 characters only

Comment: MVC 4 still isnt out, and this was posted a year ago *raises eyebrow*.

Answer (score 0):

new { style="width:50px", maxsize = 50 };

should be

new { style="width:50px", maxlength = 50 };

Answer (score 0):

Set textbox with and maxlength in mvc3.0

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SearchUrl, new { style = "width:650px;",maxlength = 250 })
```